# ¿Cómo agregar iconos de Font Awesome en android?

Tags: android, android-layout, font-awesome

Actualmente tengo un proyecto donde agregue boostrap pero ahora quisiera agregar `font-awesome` al  mismo sólo que ya realicé lo que a mi parecer era necesario para ver iconos en mis botones.

Al querer ejecutar la aplicación lo hace, pero al cabo de unos segundos se cierra inesperadamente y no me dice cuál sea el error.

Código del archivo Strings

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">OnBus</string>
    <string name="Menu1">Configuracion</string>
    <string name="Menu2">Perfil</string>
    <string name="Menu3">Historial</string>
    <string name="font_awesome_android_icon">&#xf17b;</string>
</resources>
```

Código del layout .xml (vista)

```
<com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapButton
        android:id="@+id/portada_app"
        app:bootstrapBrand="success"
        app:bootstrapSize="xl"
        app:buttonMode="regular"
        app:bootstrapText="Ingresar"
        android:text="@string/font_awesome_android_icon"
        android:layout_width="160sp"
        android:layout_height="50sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="370sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80sp"
        android:onClick="onIniciar"
/>
```

Código de la clase java

```
btnIniciar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.portada_app);
String font_path = "fontawesome-webfont.ttf";
Typeface TF = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),font_path);
btnIniciar.setTypeface(TF);
```

Comment: Mira este tutorial: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-fontawesome-in-an-android-app--cms-24167

Comment: Echale un ojo a esta [respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/35259/14088) que le puse a un compañero, igual te puede servir

Answer (score 0):

También podrías utilizar esta libreria [Iconify](https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-iconify), yo la uso en un proyecto y te permite renderizar iconos vectoriales de varias webs y funciona bastante bien.

Un saludo.