# ¿Se puede usar en Android un pack de iconos en png?

Tags: android

Estoy aprendiendo Android y estoy haciendo una aplicación del tiempo. Según el tiempo que haga quiero poner un icono diferente, mi duda es si se pueden utilizar en Android los packs de iconos que vienen en png, o si tengo que tener un icono de cada tipo en un png diferente. Y en caso de que se pueda, desde la actividad como se accedería a cada icono del png. Adjunto una muestra de los packs a los que me refiero.

Muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hay librerías de iconos para usar pero puedes también usar iconos que tu quieras por separado claro que se puede. Pero @FranciscoPagan tu pregunta no es muy concreta. ¿Has probado de hacer algo? Es el tipo de pregunta en que no sabes hacer algo y quieres que te lo hagan, da esa impresión. Deberías intentar hacer algo y si tienes problemas preguntar aquí en SOes.

Comment: Sí, he probado a poner png sueltos, eso me funciona bien, simplemente era saber si se podía hacer con un pack de png cualquiera que te descargues de internet o tenia que tener otro formato especial

Comment: Sino me equivoco lo que tu buscas es poder elegir una imagen dentro de un vector o mapa de imágenes, no se muy bien cómo se llama, y poder elegir la imagen mediante las coordenadas que tenga dentro del array o mapa. Intentaré buscar cómo se hace a ver si encuentro algo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Utilizando Librería

He encontrado un ejemplo muy parecido a lo que tu quieres hacer utilizando una librería, está en esta [página](http://blog.shamanland.com/2013/11/how-to-use-icon-fonts-in-android.html).

En dicha página explica cómo usar una librería para poder utilizar los [FontIcon](http://blog.shamanland.com/p/android-fonticon-library.html)  utilizando los archivos **.ttf** y **.css** de los packs de iconos que se pueden descargar de la [página](https://app.fontastic.me/accounts/login/) por ejemplo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### **Recursos**

Lo que hace a continuación es abrir el .css en el que se encuentran los iconos definidos de la siguiente forma:

```
.ic-quote:before {
    content: "\e000";
}
.ic-users:before {
    content: "\e001";
}
.ic-info:before {
    content: "\e002";
}
.ic-edit:before {
    content: "\e003";
}
.ic-delete:before {
    content: "\e004";
}
```

Estos son estilos con caracteres unicode de nuestros iconos. Los volveremos a escribir como recursos de cadenas. Para ello en la carpeta `res/values/` se creará un archivo .xml que se llame por ejemplo `icons.xml`

En el se volverán a escribir los estilos del .css como recursos de cadenas quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <string name="ic_quote">&#xe000;</string>
        <string name="ic_users">&#xe001;</string>
        <string name="ic_info">&#xe002;</string>
        <string name="ic_edit">&#xe003;</string>
        <string name="ic_delete">&#xe004;</string>
    </resources>
```

**Nota:** Ahora tienes un parser automático disponible: [FonIcon prepare for Android](https://github.com/shamanland/fonticon-prepare/)

El archivo con los iconos se colocará dentro de la carpeta asserts:

```
assets/icons.ttf
```

### **Gradle**

Añadir en `build.gradle`:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.shamanland:fonticon:0.1.8'
}
```

### **Código**

Hay dos clases importantes: [FontIconDrawable](https://github.com/shamanland/fonticon/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/com/shamanland/fonticon/FontIconDrawable.java) y [FontIconTypefaceHolder](https://github.com/shamanland/fonticon/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/com/shamanland/fonticon/FontIconTypefaceHolder.java). La primera extiende de la clase abstracta Drawable, y la segunda es sólo para el almacenamiento estático de la instancia Typeface cargada desde el archivo .ttf.

El archivo Typeface se inicializará en el método Application.onCreate():

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        FontIconTypefaceHolder.init(getAssets(), "icons.ttf");
    }
}
```

La utilización de `FontIconDrawable` es muy simple, por ejemplo en  `Fragment.onCreateView()`:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle state) {
    Drawable[] icons = new Drawable[]{
        FontIconDrawable.inflate(getResources(), R.xml.ic_quote),
        FontIconDrawable.inflate(getResources(), R.xml.ic_users),
        FontIconDrawable.inflate(getResources(), R.xml.ic_info),
    };

    // use drawables for any purpose
}
```

Tienes un ejemplo completo en [GitHub](https://github.com/shamanland/fonticon)

---

## Sin utilizar Librería

Por otra parte creo que esto se podía hacer sin la utilización de librerías

Utilizando **Font Awesome** cómo dice está respuesta de [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15762875/3683321) en Inglés

1. Copiar `fontawesome-webfont.ttf` en la carpeta asserts
2. Encontrar las entidades de caracteres para los iconos que quería, usando esta [página](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/)
3. Crear una entrada en `strings.xml` para cada icono. Por ejemplo, para el corazón:

   ```
   <string name="icon_heart">&#xf004;</string>
   ```
4. Referencia dicha entrada en la vista de tu diseño xml

   ```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/like"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        ...
        android:text="@string/icon_heart" />
   ```
5. Cargar la fuente en el método `onCreate` y establecerlo para las Vistas apropiadas:

   ```
   Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset( getAssets(), "fontawesome-webfont.ttf" );
   ...
   Button button = (Button)findViewById( R.id.like );
   button.setTypeface(font);
   ```

---

Por otro lado creo que se podía hacer utilizando archivos `.svg`. Pero no he encontrado nada aún, seguiré investigando el tema.

**Algunos pasos para transformar el .png a .svg**

Lo primero que deberás hacer es transformar el .png con todos los iconos a .svg. Hay muchas herramientas y servicios en línea para hacer esto, puedes utilizar [este](http://blog.shamanland.com/2013/11/how-to-use-icon-fonts-in-android.html) por ejemplo. Recuerda especificar la opción Monocromo al convertir el .png.

Comment: Muchas gracias, con esto queda solucionado.

Comment: Me alegra saber que te ha servido!! Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la carpeta `drawable` da click derecho y luego anda a `Show in explorer`
ahi solamentes pegas las imagenes y luego android studio lo sincroniza solo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
¡Funciona!
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el activity agregas un `ImageView`

```
//Para acceder a el.
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
//Para modificar la imagen.
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.nublado);
//Por ejemplo si tienes mas imagens como: soleado, nublado, lluvioso.
//Es el nombre del .png
image.setImageResource(R,drawable.soleado);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Hector, esto lo había probado antes de poner el post, quizás es que no me he explicado bien, la duda es por ejemplo como acceder al icono situado en las coordenadas 2,2 el de la nube con una flecha

Comment: Mejor con el gran y poderoso ¡PAINT! recortalas y listo.

Comment: Pues sí, la verdad es que va a ser lo mas rápido y fácil. Gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

1.- Entiendo que en Android en la carpeta de tu proyecto llamada drawable: Está donde se almacenan los ficheros de imágenes (JPG o PNG) y descriptores de imágenes en XML. Puedes ahi poner las imágenes que tu quieras, sea de librerías o no. En [este link](http://www.androidcurso.com/index.php/tutoriales-android/31-unidad-1-vision-general-y-entorno-de-desarrollo/148-elementos-de-un-proyecto-android) puedes encontrar más información.

2.- Otra opción válida podría ser que uses una librería de imágenes que te deje personalizarlas, de forma que puedas insertar tus propias imagenes como si fueran una librería.